# Can't find mistake. The value spontaneously changes

Tags: c#

Here is the code

```
for (j = 0; j < n_sign; j++)
{
    line = new List<double>();
    for (i = 0; i < n_vec; i++)
    {
        if (data_gap[i][j] != gap)
            line.Add(data_gap[i][j]);
        else
        {
            grad.Add(0);
            List<int> point = new List<int>();
            point.Add(i);
            point.Add(j);
            gaps.Add(point);
        }
    }

    List<double> mm = new List<double>();
    mm.Add(line.Min());
    mm.Add(line.Max());
    minmax.Add(mm);

    for (i = 0; i < n_vec; i++)
    {
        if (data_gap[i][j] == gap)
            data[i][j] = line[rand.Next(line.Count)];
    }
}
```

I can't understand, why after this function the values of data_gap change to the values of data!
data_gap has been created this way

```
data_gap = new List<List<double>>(data);
```

so it seems to be a unique object...

Comment: A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would really help...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`data_gap` contains the same inner lists as `data`.
You need to copy each inner list as well.